# EF Code First: Relationships with differing key names

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have two tables:

```
DocumentSet:
setId (int)
name (varchar(50))

DocIdentifier:
docIdId (int)
docSetId (int) <-- (setId from DocumentSet)
customId (char(9))
```

The typical queries done on the two tables look like this in SQL:

```
SELECT ds.name
FROM DocumentSet ds
INNER JOIN DocIdentifiers di ON ds.setId = di.docSetId
WHERE di.customId == 'someId'
```

Notice the naming difference:  `setId` and `docSetId` are the columns used for the foreign key.  The problem comes when I try to replicated this in Entity Framework.  I have the obvious models:

```
class DocumentSet {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentIdentifier> Identifiers {get;set;}
}

class DocumentIdentifier {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int SetId {get;set;}
    public string CustomId {get;set;}
    public DocumentSet DocSet {get;set;}
}
```

Again, some naming differences for clarity in the code.  So I create `EntityTypeConfiguration`s for both:

```
internal class DocumentSetTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentSet> {
    public DocumentSetTypeConfiguration () {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        Property(f => f.Id).HasColumnName("setId");
        HasMany(f => f.DocumentIdentifiers);
    }
}

internal class DocumentIdentifierTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentIdentifier> {
    public DocumentIdentifierTypeConfiguration () {
        ToTable("DocIdentifier");
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        Property(f => f.Id).HasColumnName("docIdId");
        Property(f => f.SetId).HasColumnName("docSetId");
    }
}
```

Here's the problem:  When I send a LINQ query like this:

```
_context.Set<DocumentSet>().Where(d => d.DocumentIdentifiers.Any(pt=>pt.CustomId == customId)).Single();
```

What's generated gets a little botched:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[SetId] AS [SetId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[DocumentSet] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[DocIdentifier] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[SetId] = [Extent2].[DocumentSet_Id]) AND (([Extent2].CustomId = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent2].[CustomId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
    )
```

My guess that the problem lies in the fact that `setId` and `docSetId` are different names, but I can't seem to figure out how to get EF to see that `[Extent2].[DocumentSet_Id]` should be `[Extent2].[docSet_Id]`.  Is there something I'm missing in `DocumentIdentifierTypeConfiguration` that will help EF understand this?  I thought the line `Property(f => f.SetId).HasColumnName("docSetId");` would do this, but apparently not.

In short, how do I say

```
`DocumentSet has many DocumentIdentifiers with a foreign key relationship of DocumentSet.setId = DocIdentifier.docSetId`?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [**`WithRequired`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696502%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and [**`HasForeignKey`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671294%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

```
HasMany(f => f.Identifiers).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.SetId);
```

**Full Code**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DocumentSet> DocumentSets { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DocumentSetTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DocumentIdentifierTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
public class DocumentSetTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentSet>
{
    public DocumentSetTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        Property(f => f.Id).HasColumnName("setId");
        HasMany(f => f.DocumentIdentifiers).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.SetId);
    }
}
public class DocumentIdentifierTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentIdentifier>
{
    public DocumentIdentifierTypeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("DocIdentifier");
        HasKey(f => f.Id);
        Property(f => f.Id).HasColumnName("docIdId");
        Property(f => f.SetId).HasColumnName("docSetId");
    }
}
public class DocumentSet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentIdentifier> DocumentIdentifiers { get; set; }
}
public class DocumentIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public string CustomId { get; set; }
}
```

**Database Result**

[image: Database Result]

**Query Result**

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[setId] AS [setId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[DocumentSets] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[DocIdentifier] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[setId] = [Extent2].[docSetId])
    AND   (([Extent2].[CustomId] = @p__linq__0) 
          OR (([Extent2].[CustomId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
)
```

Comment: This worked fine (with some modifications, see my answer).  Now I've just gotta figure out why suddenly EF isn't actually connecting to the database anymore...

Comment: @StephenCollins, you don't have to add `DocSet` (but if you want, you could), just tried adding above code, it should work, `WithRequired` can accept empty argument after specifying `HasMany`, and if you use `MapKey`, the foreign key value in the class `public int SetId {get;set;}` will not connect as foreign key

Comment: Your suggestion *sounds* right, but the problem again is the naming.  You suggestion lands me a `ModelValidationException`, while the `MapKey` approach *would* generate the models/queries correctly, but the problem lies here:  `HasMany(ds => ds.Identifiers).WithRequired().Map(di => di.MapKey("docSetId"));`.  This fails because and tells me ` Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'docSetId' is already defined.`

Comment: @StephenCollins, I posted the full code and the result, could you point out what's missing ?

Comment: Your code works fine in a new project.  I must have other problems not noted in my code.  I've got more digging to do.  Thank you.